# Trouble in analog clock widget javafx

Tags: widget, javafx, clock

With Reference to

https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2658491

Here is my code block that is causing error ( marked with *)

```
    Calendar time = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    double second = time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    double minute = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    double hour   = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    double secondStartPos = 6*second;
    double minuteStartPos = 6*minute;
    double hourStartPos   = 30*hour + (0.5*minuteStartPos);

    //Define rotations
    Rotate secondRotate = new Rotate(secondStartPos, 150, 150);
    Rotate minuteRotate = new Rotate(minuteStartPos, 150, 150);
    Rotate hourRotate = new Rotate(  hourStartPos, 150, 150);
    secondHand.getTransforms().add(secondRotate);
    minuteHand.getTransforms().add(minuteRotate);
    hourHand.getTransforms().add(hourRotate);


    //Time line for second
    Timeline secondTime = new Timeline(
    *        new KeyFrame(
             Duration.seconds(60),
    **       new KeyValue(
             secondRotate.angleProperty(),
             360 + secondStartPos ,
             Interpolator.LINEAR
             )
             )
             );
```

And the errors are

*The constructor KeyFrame(Duration, KeyValue) is undefined

**The constructor KeyValue(DoubleProperty, double, Interpolator) is undefined

I looked at the API Docs

docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html

but couldnt figure out what is the error.
Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not importing the right class:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
```

Probably you are importing some other KeyValue class from the JDK (such as com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.keys.content.KeyValue).

[There is a newer and higher quality version of the code on which you are basing your implementation](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637).

Comment: Thanx a lot. That solved it. I was working in eclipse and had mistakenly imported keyValue from that security package (described by u).